# Do effectively immutable objects make sense?

Tags: java, thread-safety, immutability

In the book [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://jcip.net/) it explains the advantages of "effectively immutable" objects versus mutable objects concurrency-wise.  But it does not explain what advantage "effectively immutables" objects would offer over *really* immutable objects.

And I don't get it: can't you *always* build a really immutable object at the moment you'd decide to publish safely an "effectively immutable" object? *(instead of doing your "safe publication" you'd build a really immutable object and that's it)*

When I'm designing classes I fail to see cases where I couldn't always build a truly immutable object (using delegation if needed etc. to build other wrapped objects, themselves truly immmutable of course) at the moment I'd decide to "safely publish".

So are "effectively immutable" object and their "safe publication" just a case of bad design or poor APIs?

Where would you be forced to use an effectively immutable object and be forced to safely publish it where you couldn't build a much superior really immutable object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they make sense in some cases. An easy example is when you want some property to be generated lazily and cached so you can avoid the overhead of generating it if it's never accessed. `String` is an example of an effectively immutable class that does this (with its hashcode).

Answer (score 4):

For circular immutables:

```
class Foo
{
    final Object param;
    final Foo other;

    Foo(Object param, Foo other)
    {
        this.param = param;
        this.other = other;
    }

    // create a pair of Foo's, A=this, B=other
    Foo(Object paramA, Object paramB)
    {
        this.param = paramA;
        this.other = new Foo(paramB, this);
    }

    Foo getOther(){ return other; }
}



// usage
Foo fooA = new Foo(paramA, paramB);
Foo fooB = fooA.getOther();
// publish fooA/fooB (unsafely)
```

A question is, since `this` of `fooA` is leaked inside constructor, is `fooA` still a thread safe immutable? That is, if another thread reads `fooB.getOther().param`, is it guaranteed to see `paramA`? The answer is yes, since `this` is not leaked to another thread before the *freeze* action; we can establish hb/dc/mc orders required by spec to prove that `paramA` is the only visible value for the read.

Back to your original question. In practice there are always constraints beyond the pure technical ones. Initialize everything inside constructor is not necessarily the best option for a design, considering all engineering, operational, political and other human-ish reasons.

Ever wondering why we are fed to think that it is a great supreme idea?

The deeper problem is Java *lacks* a general cheap fense for safe publication which is cheaper than volatile. Java only has it for `final` fields; for some reason, that fence is not available otherwise.

Now `final` carries two independent meanings: 1st, that a final field must be assigned exactly once; 2nd, the memory semantics of safe publication. These two meanings have nothing to do with each other. It is quite confusing to bundle them together. When people need the 2nd meaning, they are forced to accept the 1st meaning too. When the 1st is very inconvenient to achieve in a design, people wonder what they have done wrong - not realizing that it's Java that did wrong.

Bundling of two meanings under one `final` makes it double plus good, so that apparently we have more reason and motivation to use `final`. The more sinister story is actually we are forced to use it because we are not given a more flexible choice.

Comment: +1 for the great example and explanation.  Also I didn't mention "final" but that is indeed what we have to use...  Regarding the two meanings: it's even more confusing seen that *final* can also be applied to methods but I digress ; )      I like the constructor example although one could also do it using a factory and/or a fluent interface.

Answer (score 1):

Using effectively immutable objects lets you avoid creating a considerable number of classes. Instead of making pairs of [mutable builder]/[immutable object] classes, you can build one effectively immutable class. I usually define an immutable interface, and a mutable class that implements this interface. An object is configured through its mutable class methods, and then published through its immutable interface. As long as the clients of your library program to the interface, to them your objects remain immutable through their published lifetime.

Comment: Any example of this approach available ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose one has an immutable class `Foo` with five properties, named `Alpha`, `Beta`, etc., and one wishes to provide `WithAlpha`, `WithBeta`, etc. methods which will return an instance which is identical to the original except with the particular property changed.  If the class is truly and deeply immutable, the methods have to take the form:

```
Foo WithAlpha(string newAlpha)
{ 
  return new Foo(newAlpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta, Epsilon);
}

Foo WithBeta(string newBeta) 
{
  return new Foo(Alpha, NewBeta, Gamma, Delta, Epsilon);
}
```

Ick.  A massive violation of "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY) principles.  Further, adding a new property to the class would require adding it to every single one of those methods.

On the other hand, if each `Foo` held an internal `FooGuts` which included a copy constructor, one could instead do something like:

```
Foo WithAlpha(string newAlpha)
{
  FooGuts newGuts = new FooGuts(Guts); // Guts is a private or protected field
  newGuts.Alpha = newAlpha;
  return new Foo(newGuts); // Private or protected constructor
}
```

The number of lines of code for each method has increased, but the methods no longer need to make any reference to any properties they aren't "interested" in.  Note that while a `Foo` might not be immutable if its constructor were called with a `FooGuts` to which any outside reference existed, its constructor is only accessible to code which is trusted not to maintain any such reference after construction.